# PHP/MySQL: Strange output issue when echoing variable from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that contains names and e-mail addresses. The data was originally imported from a .csv file, and it did not originally contain complete e-mail addresses. We had to append the @place.domain to the user's alias.

When the data is sitting in the MySQL table, it looks normal: person@place.domain; however, when I output the content in PHP, I get this: person @place.domain. There's always a space between the person and the @. It doesn't look like that in the MySQL column, nor does it look like that when I copy/paste the data into Notepad, Word, Excel, etc. Furthermore, if I *erase* the data in the column and manually replace it with person@place.domain, it displays normally in my PHP app. So I'm guessing there's some hidden character that PHP is picking up that I can't detect. Is there a way for me to clean this up? I've tried TRIM(), REPLACE,(), etc., all to no avail.

UPDATE: I've discovered that, when I click in the MySQL field and move among the characters using my arrow keys, I have to hit the arrow key TWICE to move past the @ symbol, yet there is no visible space.

Comment: How do you check the data "sitting in the MySQL table"? How do you output it in PHP? Can you show us any code?

Comment: In DBs there are such things as NULL, nothing, literal space, and padding space. I think you are a victim of padding space. I would recommend pulling all of your records with a `select`, exploding the email with `$email_parts = explode('@', $row['email']);`, trim and join the parts back together `$email = trim(email_parts[0]).'@'.trim($email_parts[1]);`, and then update the record with the new email address while looping the SELECT.

Comment: @Sébastien: When I do a simple return all rows in MySQL, the fields appear normal. No spaces. but when I click inside any of the e-mail address fields and move among the characters, I have to hit the arrow key twice to move past the @ symbol. That indicates to me that there's some hidden character in the field.

My output code is just a simple echo statement after a prepared statement selects the field: 
    echo $row['emailaddress'];

Answer (score 1):

I made this sample code for you:

```
<?php

 $test = "user @mail.com";
 $aux = explode("@",$test);

 $mailok = trim($aux[0])."@".trim($aux[1]);
 echo $test."     vs  ".$mailok;   

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely something like non-breaking space (ascii 160). To get rid of it:

```
UPDATE my_table SET e_mail = REPLACE(e_mail, CHAR(160), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a foreach cycle, and do the chr($char) function to every character in the string, it will display you the ascii code  of  each  character in the string, and you will find the wrong character. It's the only solution I found. Hope to be useful